# My javascript function for clearing a form text input field is not working

Tags: javascript, html, function, web

Even though a lot of work is left, the basic calculator is done, everything is working just fine except the clear function. I can not get it to clear the viewer. need immediate help please.

**(i put everything in one file so it is easy for everyone to understand the full thing)**

Please avoid the styling tho.

So basically i made this extremely simple calculator with the function clear()
Any ideas on how i can make this function in order to clear the viewer?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>


<script>
  function insert(num) {
    document.view.viewer.value = document.view.viewer.value+num
  }
  function equal() {
    document.view.viewer.value = eval(document.view.viewer.value);
  }
  function clear() {
    document.view.viewer.value = "";
  }
</script>


<style>
body {
  background-image: url("peepee.png"); 
}
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.button {
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:grey;
  text-align:center;
  margin:2px;
  font-size: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0px;
}
.clear {
  height:100px;
  width:400px;
  background-color: red;
  text-align:center;
  margin:2px;
  font-size: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0px;  
}
.viewer {
  height: 100px;
  width: 430px;
  font-size: 50px;
  margin: 2px
}
</style>


</head>


<body>
  <div class= "main">
    <form name= "view">
      <input class="viewer" name= "viewer">
    </form>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><input class="button" value="7" onclick= "insert(7)"></td>
        <td><input class="button" value="8" onclick= "insert(8)"></td>
        <td><input class="button" value="9" onclick= "insert(9)"></td>
        <td><input class="button" value="-" onclick= "insert('/')"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input class="button" value="4" onclick= "insert(4)"></td>
        <td><input class="button" value="5" onclick= "insert(5)"></td>
        <td><input class="button" value="6" onclick= "insert(6)"></td>
        <td><input class="button" value="x" onclick= "insert('*')"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input class="button" value="1" onclick= "insert(1)"></td>
        <td><input class="button" value="2" onclick= "insert(2)"></td>
        <td><input class="button" value="3" onclick= "insert(3)"></td>
        <td><input class="button" value="-" onclick= "insert('-')"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input class="button" value="0" onclick= "insert(0)"></td>
        <td><input class="button" value="." onclick= "insert('.')"></td>
        <td><input class="button" value="=" onclick= "equal()"></td>
        <td><input class="button" value="+" onclick= "insert('+')"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><input class= "clear" value="Clear" onclick= "clear()"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so I figured out solution you are not giving a type of your `input`
>   and change your `clear` function to something else `clearText`. It
>   seems that `clear` function is some kind of inbuilt function
>   and put `defer` attribute in your script tag so that it will load after the `body`

`function clearText() {
    console.log("Clear Button clicked!");
    document.view.viewer.value = "";
};`

`<td><input type="button" class="clear" value="Clear" onclick="clearText()" /></td>`

Comment: same time answered. This is actual issue in your function calling. Upvoting this.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Sajjan Karn. The JavaScript `clear` function is an default function which clears the JavaScript console.

In this case, simply rename the function to `clearView` for example:

```
<script>
  function insert(num) {
    document.view.viewer.value = document.view.viewer.value+num
  }
  function equal() {
    document.view.viewer.value = eval(document.view.viewer.value);
  }
  function clearView() {
    document.view.viewer.value = "";
  }
</script>
```

And the HTML for the button:

```
<input class= "clear" value="Clear" onclick= "clearView()">
```

In the future, I would try using the `addEventListener` function instead of manually adding the `onclick` attribute to buttons, like this:

```
<script>
    document.querySelector('input.clear').addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.view.viewer.value = '';
    });
</script>
```

I hope this answers your question, and good luck with the calculator!

Answer (score 0):

```js
function insert(num) {

    document.view.viewer.value = document.view.viewer.value+num
  }
  function equal() {
    document.view.viewer.value = eval(document.view.viewer.value);
  }
  function clearInput() {
  document.view.viewer.value = "";
  }
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url("peepee.png"); 
}
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.button {
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:grey;
  text-align:center;
  margin:2px;
  font-size: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0px;
}
.clear {
  height:100px;
  width:400px;
  background-color: red;
  text-align:center;
  margin:2px;
  font-size: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0px;  
}
.viewer {
  height: 100px;
  width: 430px;
  font-size: 50px;
  margin: 2px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>


<script>
  
</script>


<style>

</style>


</head>


<body>
  <div class= "main">
    <form name= "view">
      <input class="viewer" name= "viewer">
    </form>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><input class="button" value="7" onclick= "insert(7)"></td>
        <td><input class="button" value="8" onclick= "insert(8)"></td>
        <td><input class="button" value="9" onclick= "insert(9)"></td>
        <td><input class="button" value="-" onclick= "insert('/')"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input class="button" value="4" onclick= "insert(4)"></td>
        <td><input class="button" value="5" onclick= "insert(5)"></td>
        <td><input class="button" value="6" onclick= "insert(6)"></td>
        <td><input class="button" value="x" onclick= "insert('*')"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input class="button" value="1" onclick= "insert(1)"></td>
        <td><input class="button" value="2" onclick= "insert(2)"></td>
        <td><input class="button" value="3" onclick= "insert(3)"></td>
        <td><input class="button" value="-" onclick= "insert('-')"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input class="button" value="0" onclick= "insert(0)"></td>
        <td><input class="button" value="." onclick= "insert('.')"></td>
        <td><input class="button" value="=" onclick= "equal()"></td>
        <td><input class="button" value="+" onclick= "insert('+')"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><input class= "clear" value="Clear" onclick= "clearInput()" type="button" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>


</html>
```